# matplotlib PGF output: Contour labels extend beyond figure boundary

Tags: python, matplotlib, pgf

Taking the first example from the [`matplotlib` examples page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html),

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)


# Create a simple contour plot with labels using default colors.  The
# inline argument to clabel will control whether the labels are draw
# over the line segments of the contour, removing the lines beneath
# the label
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')

plt.savefig('plot.pgf')
```

I have the problem that contour labels close to the axes (here, “0.000” at the very top) jut out beyond the figure boundary. Here is the output I get using LaTeX:
[image: Contour plot produced with PGF/LaTeX]
As you can see, the label “0.000” at the top overlaps the black line.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? To be clear, my issue is *not* that the label is close to the axis. What I want is the same behavior as shown on the [`matplotlib` page](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html), namely that the plot content is clipped to the figure area, cutting off text as well as lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the [corresponding bug report for `matplotlib` (#11375)](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11375), `matplotlib`’s PGF backend does not support text clipping, which is causing this issue, which still seems to persist today.